# Forecasting of ratios that need to addup to 100%

Tags: forecasting, ratio, constraint

I intend to forecast 'shares' or ratios independently that need to add up to 100% . How can I do this especially when there are >2 ratios to predict. e.g. share of mdot, share of desktop and sahre of app ?

Comment: Some info https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compositional_data.

Comment: I came across this as well : https://forecasters.org/wp-content/uploads/gravity_forms/7-621289a708af3e7af65a7cd487aee6eb/2015/07/Ord_Keith_ISF2015.pdf